# Can someone explain how the routine below is logging "undefined" in console?

Tags: javascript

Code snippet below suppose to log sum of digits in the given number.But, it returns undefined. Can someone please explain how it works under the hood?

```js
const checkNumbers = (membershipId) => {
  if (membershipId.length === 1) {
    return membershipId;
  }
  if (membershipId.length > 1) {
    sumOfNumbers = [...membershipId].reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0);
    checkNumbers(sumOfNumbers.toString());
  }
};

console.log(checkNumbers("555"));
```

Comment: You had one `+` too much here  `+a + +b`. There seems something wrong there, but with only one + I get "too much recursion".

Comment: @Sascha the +'s right next to the variables are converting them into numbers. Then the numbers are added.

Comment: @Nicholas Tower - Thanks, I would have used parseInt but this is shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because except for the length === 1 case, you don't have a return statement. If there's no return statement, then `undefined` is returned implicitly once the end of the function is reached.

To fix it, change this:

```
checkNumbers(sumOfNumbers.toString());
```

To this:

```
return checkNumbers(sumOfNumbers.toString());
```

Full code:

```js
const checkNumbers = (membershipId) => {
  if (membershipId.length === 1) {
    return membershipId;
  }
  if (membershipId.length > 1) {
    sumOfNumbers = [...membershipId].reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0);
    return checkNumbers(sumOfNumbers.toString());
  }
};

console.log(checkNumbers('555'));
```